# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - form object is null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm caught up on this error and beating my head - it seemed like it would be a real form so this error (and my inability to resolve it) has me going insane.

I am simply trying to update 1 field in a table. The field being updated may or may not be null.

I'm getting an error in the controller. The 'ilpCareerGoal' object is coming back null and causes the error.

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult editCareerGoal(int emplID)
    {
        ilpCareerGoal careerGoal = qService.getCareerGoal(emplID);
        return View(careerGoal);
    }

[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult editCareerGoal(ilpCareerGoal careerGoal)
    {
        try
        {
            qService.editCareerGoal(careerGoal);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch
        {               
            throw;
        }

    }
```

View:

```
@model ILP.Models.ilpCareerGoal

@{
ViewBag.Title = "editCareerGoal";
}

<h2>Edit Your Career Goal</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("editCareerGoal", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "careerGoalForm" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Career Goal</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.emplID)
        Record information here about what you're striving for professionally.
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.careerGoal, new { cols = "90", rows = "15" })
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

When I debug I see that 'careerGoal' in my controller is null... I appreciate any help here!

Update - maybe it's a model thing? I actually have this field in a different model... here's my model code for the update just in case....

Model:

```
public bool editCareerGoal(ilpCareerGoal tcareerGoal)
        {
            employeeDataClassesDataContext careerGoals = new employeeDataClassesDataContext();
            ilpCareerGoal careerGoal;

            try
            {                   
                careerGoal = careerGoals.ilpCareerGoals.Single(c => c.emplID == tcareerGoal.emplID);
                careerGoal.careerGoal = tcareerGoal.careerGoal;
                careerGoals.SubmitChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looking at the code all seems ok to me. Can you post also the code in which you initialize the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the name collision between the property `careerGoal` in the `ilpCareerGoal` class and the variable named `careerGoal` of type `ilpCareerGoal` in your `editCareerGoal` action is causing the DefaultModelBinder to have a nervous breakdown.

Try changing the name of the variable in your action to something different, such as `careerGoalModel`.

Comment: Interesting - this seems to have done the trick! Thanks very much.